# Анимация перехода на другую страницу React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animation, react-router

Пытаюсь сделать анимацию перехода на другую страницу следующим образом: Для начала я обернул в `HashRouter` мой контейнер, который меняется при смене адреса.Далее я создал компонент второй страницы, для которой прописал два класса со стилями, первый основной. в которой все дефолтные свойства + скрытие за пределы `body`, т.е. `transform: translateX(100%);` и `transition 0.4s;`, а второму классу, который добавляется при изменении состояния компонента дал `transform: translateX(0);`. В итоге анимация не работает, хотя я использую `componentDidMoutn()`, т.е. после того как компонент уже отрендерился я меняю его состояние. Новая страница появляется моментально, а не плавно выплывает.

Код самой страницы, которая должна появится:

```js
import React from 'react';

import './SearchPage.css';

class SearchPage extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        
        this.state= {
            onDisplay: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            onDisplay: true,
        })
    }

    render() {

        let classList = '';

        if(this.state.onDisplay == false) {
            classList = 'SearchPage';
        } else {
            classList = 'SearchPage SearchPage--active';
        }

        return(
            <div className={classList}></div>
        )
    }
}

export default SearchPage;
```

```css
.SearchPage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: .4s;
}

.SearchPage--active {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Код страницы на которой происходит навигация:

```js
import React from 'react';

import MainPage from '../MainPage';
import LeftNav from '../LeftNav';
import SearchPage from '../SearchPage';
import Menu from '../Menu';
import './App.css';

import {HashRouter, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            open: false,
        }

        this.onOpen = () => {
            this.setState({
                open: !this.state.open,
            })
        }
    }


    render() {

        let classList = '';

        if(this.state.open == true) {
            classList = 'main-wrapper main-wrapper--active';
        } else {
            classList = 'main-wrapper'
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <Menu onOpen={this.onOpen} />
                <HashRouter>
                    <main className={classList}>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage} />
                        <Route exact path='/search' component={SearchPage} />
                    </main>
                </HashRouter>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что CSS анимация при добавлении класса `.SearchPage--active` не отрабатывает, потому что нет ререндера и значение `transform` не меняется, а ставится сразу в `translateX(0);`. Чтобы инициировать изменение этого значения можно использовать `setTimeout`. В этом случае страница отрендерится с начальным значением `transform: translateX(100%);`, а потом по таймауту перерендерит с новым класом и значением. Но смелюсь предложить второй вариант, без ререндера и JS в целом, который является очевидно производительнее.

Вариант №1: `setTimeout`

```js
class SearchPage extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        
        this.state= {
            onDisplay: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            onDisplay: true,
        })
      }, 0)
    }

    render() {

        let classList = '';

        if(this.state.onDisplay === false) {
            classList = 'SearchPage';
        } else {
            classList = 'SearchPage SearchPage--active';
        }

        return(
            <div className={classList}>lala</div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SearchPage/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.SearchPage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.SearchPage--active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Вариант №2: `CSS animation`

```js
class SearchPage extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount() {}

    render() {
        return(
            <div className='SearchPage'></div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SearchPage/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```css
.SearchPage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  animation: slideIn 0.4s;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```